# Put a graphic card into low energy mode

Tags: power-management

I have a home PC server with a PCIe graphic card (not integrated into the CPU or motherboard). This graphic card has a fan to keep it cool which involve some noise, and the electric consumption seems not negligible (heat involve power).

This server has no GUI, and I rarely use the console (mainly SSH).
I do not plan to remove or change any hardware.

I search a way to power down the graphic card, or put it in a low energy mode.
When a computer goes into sleep mode, the graphic card is also put in sleep mode. So there is a way to power it down, but I found nothing.

I already disabled Nouveau, and KMS, and put the screen in to sleep mode via DPMS. But the graphic card remain hot and noisy.

Any idea how to reduce the power slurped by a graphic card when its not used?
Ideally, the graphic card would resuscitate when the keyboard is used.